# Python counting item's appearances in list

Tags: python

Given

```
listEx = ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'apple', 'bird', 'bird']

for i in listEx:
    if listEx.count(i) > 1:
        print "this item appears more than once", i
    else:
        print "this item appears only once", i
```

I want it to print that cat and bird appear more than once (or just produce `['cat', 'bird']`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

The *[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)* tool makes this sort of task really easy:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> listEx = ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'apple', 'bird', 'bird']
>>> [k for k, cnt in Counter(listEx).items() if cnt > 1]
['bird', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> [v for v, r in itertools.groupby(sorted(listEx)) if len(list(r)) > 1]
['bird', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 2):

All previous answers are great. I just wanted to point out, that you could also simply use a dictionary to count your items:

```
>>> listEx = ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'apple', 'bird', 'bird']
>>> d = dict()
>>> for v in listEx: d[v] = d[v] + 1 if v in d else 1
...
>>> d
{'turtle': 1, 'bird': 2, 'apple': 1, 'dog': 1, 'cat': 2}
>>> for v in d:
...     if d[v] > 1:
...             print v
...
bird
cat
>>>
```

Comment: I think you mean `d.get(v, 0)`. Or even `d = collections.defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do the counting:

```
from collections import defaultdict

animals = ["cat", "dog", "cat", "turtle", "apple", "bird", "bird"]

animal_counts = defaultdict(int)
for animal in animals:
    animal_counts[animal] += 1

print([animal for animal, count in animal_counts.items() if count > 1])
# ['cat', 'bird']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[word for word in set(listEx) if listEx.count(word) > 1]
```